# Showing $\cfrac ab$ is not an integer, $a$, $b$ integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, integers

Given integers $a, b$ with $b \neq 0$, suppose there is $n \geq 2$ such that $n |b$ but $n \nmid a$. Show $\frac{a}{b}$ is not an integer.

I'm not entirely certain about this but does supposing $n \geq 2, n |b$ but $n \nmid a$ tell us about $a, b$ being coprime? If so, the proof is easy enough to follow from there. Otherwise i'm not sure.

Comment: If n|b and b|a then n|a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer, call it $k$.

Then $a=bk$, or in other words $b|a$. You also know that $n|b$. What can you conclude from here?

Comment: Implies n | a, but that gives us a contradiction. Thanks!